# Large Resultset with Spring Boot and QueryDSL

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I have a Spring Boot application where I use QueryDSL for dynamic queries. 
Now the results should be exported as a csv file. 
The model is an `Order` which contains products. The products should be included in the csv file. 
However, as there are many thousand orders with millions of products this should not be loaded into memory at once.

However, solutions proposed by Hibernate (`ScrollableResults`) and streams are not supported by QueryDSL.

How can this be achieved while still using QueryDSL (to avoid duplication of filtering logic)?

Comment: Create a query and use `iterate` instead of `fetch`. This will return a lazy iterator and retrieve data on demand. Underneath it uses a `ScrollableResults`.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround to this problem is to keep iterating using `offset` and `limit`.

Something like:

```
long limit = 100;
long lastLimitUsed = 0;

List<MyEntity> entities = new JPAQuery<>(em)
    .from(QMyEntity.entity)
    .limit(limit)
    .offset(lastLimitUsed)
    .fetch();
lastLimitUsed += limit;
```

With that approach you can fetch smaller chunks of data. It is important to analyze if the `limit` and `offset` field will work well with your query. There are situations where even if you use `limit` and `offset` you will end up making a full scan on the tables involved on the query. If that happens you will face a performance problem instead of a memory one.

Answer (score 0):

Use JPAQueryFactory

```java
// com.querydsl.jpa.impl.JPAQueryFactory
JPAQueryFactory jpaFctory = new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager);

//
Expression<MyEntity> select = QMyEntity.myEntity;
EntityPath<MyEntity> path = QMyEntity.myEntity;

Stream stream = this.jpaQueryFactory
            .select(select)
            .from(entityPath)
            .where(cond)
            .createQuery()   // get jpa query
            .getResultStream();

// do something
stream.close();
```